# How to chain together points in an array

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures, performance

I have a series of points with lengths and rotations like this:

[image: Points]

I need to create separate chains from points whose lines overlap but I’m having real trouble doing this efficiently.

I have an array of simple Point objects, in no particular order, and I can loop through them and test them with a simple "intersect" function. I need to end up with an array of chains, each with an ordered list of points. (Or another way of representing the chains).

At the moment every avenue I explore seems to involve a convoluted hack of arrays, nudges and fudges. Having never studied Computer Science I wonder if there is some sort of data structure or technique that would lend itself well to this sort of thing.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to achieving this? Pseudocode is fine (or indeed any language), although I am coding in Processing/Java if that helps.

Many thanks,

Josh

Comment: I believe this is better suited at [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Saw your thread again. You should consider moving your question there as you'd probably gain more help there.

Comment: The reason he is suggesting that is that this is not a trivial problem. That exchange is more suited to conceptual problems. If you want to research more on it, look into machine learning algorithms, that seems to be what this problem would fall into.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll move the question.

Comment: Seems like a job for [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [union-find algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to find joined sets.

If your sets always are well-defined (there are no multiple intersections and so on), then some modifications seem possible to build chains during join process:
for every set, besides a 'representative', keep two extreme segments, and modify them when joining.